# will ARM CPU's cache be invalided after access from cache disabled virtual address?

Tags: caching, arm

accroding to `Cortex ™ -A7 MPCore Technical Reference Manual`, `6.4 L1 data memory system` data cache's tag is a part of physical address, am i right?
here is the reference:

> The L1 data cache is organized as a physically indexed and physically tagged cache.
>   The micro  TLB produces the physical address from the virtual address
>   before performing the cache access.

If I am right, what will happen after write data to a virtual address with cache disabled attribute.
for example: cache enabled virtual address `0xc000_0000` and cache disabled virtual address `0xd000_0000` are both mapped to physicall `0x4000_0000`.
Will the cache be invalidated when I write data to `0xc000_0000'?

Comment: Did you try this experiment?

Comment: No, I dont know how to setting the MMU. of course I can read the CPU manual, but that will spend too much time because I am not familiar with that.

Comment: Of course not.  You said the memory is un-cached.  To know to flush, each and every uncached address would have to search the MMU for a duplicate mapping.  Also, this behavior maybe desired.  You may do work and then flush/invalidate a range instead of continually flushing and read/write behavior will dictate whether you need a flush or invalidate.  Dual mappings like this depend on the use case of the backing physical memory.

Comment: when you go read the manuals, the amba/axi bus has many transaction types if you count the cache bit settings and the exclusive settings for example.  all the mmu table does is help manipulate those.  The quote from the manual is simply stating that the L1 cache is on the physical side, not on the virtual side.  invalidating the cache is an inside the cache thing not a memory bus thing. if you map two or more virtual addresses to the same memory space, then you can have a race condition for starters, add caching and it just gets worse.  both/all paths hit the same memory space though.

Comment: when you write to 0xC0000000 it gets translated to 0x40000000 the transaction then goes out to L1 as cachable and whatever happens in the cache is based on history, is it a hit or miss.  If you then write to 0xD0000000 and the mmu has that as cache disabled, it goes out marked as not cacheable on the bus, and should pass right through the cache uninspected.  If 0x40000000 is in the cache, then now you have a coherency problem, the ram on the far side does not match what the cache thinks should be there.

Comment: Thanks old_timer, I think your reply is the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

old_timer answered the question see his comment